Upgrade React Navigation 6 to 7, now back button in nested stack will crash app
I recently upgraded my app and I've noticed that the top nav row buttons are crashing my app.
Before upgrade:
All buttons in top nav row worked - back button, custom buttons in headerRight
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.16",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.4.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.4.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^17.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "formik": "^2.4.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^3.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "victory-native": "^36.6.10",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"

After upgrade:
High in the app - back button still works, but custom headerRight buttons stopped working.
Lower in the app - back button crashes the app, AND custom headerRight buttons not working.
"@notifee/react-native": "9.1.2",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "0.5.17",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.5.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "21.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "21.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "21.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "7.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "7.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "7.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "7.0.1",
    "formik": "2.4.6",
    "json5": "2.2.3",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "luxon": "3.5.0",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.5.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.14.0",
    "react-native-screens": "4.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "15.8.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "10.2.0",
    "victory-native": "37.3.1",
    "yup": "1.4.0"

Any idea why upgrading might've borked my (previously working) app?
Thanks

If you have a crash then you should share the crash log. The list of dependencies isn't that useful.
